# module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping

Tags: apache2, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

Please help me out, I have been trying to resolve this error from a long time.

When I restart apache & type this `:sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -t` 
I get an output like this:
**[Fri Aug 24 17:02:58 2012] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping

Syntax OK**

What is going wrong? I have checked the wsgi.load file in etc/apache2/mods-enabled. It loads the mod_wsgi.so only once. I have installed libapache-mod-wsgi from the source & I'm using python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 10):

First check whether you have two lines anywhere saying:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

If you don't, then the one file that it is listed in, must be getting included twice.

So look for any Include lines in the files and see whether the file could be included more than once a a result of them. Be especially careful of how wildcards work in Include directive.

Comment: I am unable to trace out the error.  i searched all the files & found one of the files missing: /var/www/py/wsgi_handler.wsgi. is this necessary??

Comment: can u also mention what all files to check??

Comment: Check the Apache configuration files for the 'Include' directive. How you have set them up must mean there is an Include that is likely including the file twice. Else you made the mistake of creating a backup file and because of a wildcard for an Include it is also including the backup file.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading those modules more than once. Try a search and comment or delete duplicate lines:

**In Centos/ RHEL:**

```
grep ssl_module -rI /etc/httpd/*   
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

In this case I commented out line in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` so all SSL stuff live in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

Same for `mod_wsgi`

```
grep mod_wsgi -rI /etc/httpd/*
```

**In Debian/ Ubuntu:**

```
grep ssl_module -rI /etc/apache2/*
```